# How to communicate between two google apps scripts embedded in one google site?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have two published web apps (script 1 and script 2) embedded in a google sites page. The simplest way to communicate to both scripts seems to be to  call the page with GET parameters:

```
https://sites.google.com/a/some.place.com/home?tab=1
```

Then both embedded scripts can read the parameters:

```
function doGet(requestInfo) 
{
   var tab = requestInfo.parameters['tab'];
}
```

However if I create a link in script 1

```
var url = SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl();
<a href='url + "?tab=1"' target="_top"> <a/>
```

then after clicking the link the request is either loaded into the first script's frame by setting the target to _self, _parent, _top or popped as a _blank page in a new tab. This is not ideal.

If I use the ScriptApp class to:

```
var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
href='url + "?tab=1"';
```

in script 1 then clicking the link only sends the parameters to script 1 and not script 2.

Is there a better way to communicate between two scripts embedded in a site?

Answer (score 0):

There is no practical way to do it.
Your first method with target will fail because of browser limitations not because of gas, an iframe cannot target top.
The 2nd method only sends to one script.

Its possible but impractical to keep the scripts always running (with hmtService interval or uiService with repeated server handlers) and keep checking some shared store, but it will consume your quotas and other problems. Besides it requires extra work to keep the view per user/session.

Comment: Thanks for the confirming my fears. What browser limitation does not allow a link in an iframe to target _top? This little nugget makes me think this is a gas issue: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#anchor_tags)